# Every subgroup is a union of cyclic subgroups of its group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

True or false? Every subgroup H of a group G is a union of cyclic subgroups
of G.

I think it is false,but cant think of counter example

Answer (score 5):

True. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $H=\bigcup_{h\in H}\langle h\rangle$.